# Can I call a derived class constructor from a base class?

Tags: c++

If I have a base class.

```
class Base{
   ...
};
```

and a derived class

```
class Derived : public Base{
   ...
}
```

Can I call the Derived class constructor from the main() class, if I only include Base class ?

To clarify what I mean. Can I do this?

```
#include "Base.h"

int main(){
  Derived d;
}
```

Note: The only answers I was able to find were if I can call Base constructor from Derived class, but I want to do the opposite.

I only include "Base.h". Do I have to include "Derived.h" to call the constructor? What if I had 150 subclasses under one superclass? Do I have to include each one ?

Comment: You must include it.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: @Nidhoegger I am trying to understand how inheritance works in C++. What if I had a super class with 100 subclasses? Should I need to include them all?

Comment: @MariosAth anytime you specifically reference a class, the include must be included in that file. Otherwise, you don't define the reference to that derived object.

Comment: You can't use something until it has been declared first. So yes, you need to include the header file of every class you intend to instantiate

Comment: @RemyLebeau a mere declaration is not sufficient though. The class must be *defined* before it can be instantiated.

Comment: Maybe you want the Factory Pattern function, where the calling code calls the factory, but itself doesn't know about Derived.  The factory returns a (say) `std::unique_ptr<Base> MakeBase()`, but really it is a Derived rather than Base because the factory knows about both Base and Derived.  (If there were 100 derived classes, the factory would create-and-return the correct one based on parameters.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot call a derived class constructor from a base class. The base class has *no idea* the derived class even exist.

Comment: Technically, you **can** call a derived class constructor from a base class. But you probably never need to.

Answer (score 1):

Constructors have a special job of initializing the object properly. A Derived class constructor has access only to its own class members, but a Derived class object also have inherited property of Base class, and only base class constructor can properly initialize base class members. Hence all the constructors are called, else object wouldn't be constructed properly.source:

https://www.studytonight.com/cpp/order-of-constructor-call.php

Whenever the derived class’s default constructor is called, the base class’s default constructor is called automatically.Whenever the derived class inherited  base class Constructors couldn't inherited in any mode(public,private,protected)

Answer (score 0):

You derived class should include Base.h since it is needed for compilation. You then can include Derived in your main file.

Answer (score 0):

When a derived object is constructed, it calls the base default constructor automatically. If you don't want it to call the base default constructor and call a non-default constructor, then you do something like this:

```
Derived::Derived() : Base(/*Parameters to call base non-default constructor here*/)
{
    //Do stuff specifically for the derived class
}
```

If you don't include any constructors at all, then the compiler will add one for you (basically setting all the variables to the compiler's default values.

The order in which these occur are

1. Base Constructor (Non-default if you specify like above)
2. Derived Constructor

Also, with your includes, any object that you are going to refer to in main must be included.

Comment: That is not my question though. I am not asking the order in which constructors are called. I am asking if I can call a derived class from the base class.

Comment: I see. That wasn't clear in your question. Then the answer is no. Just like @Jesper Juhl said. "The base class has no idea the derived class even exists"

Comment: I see. Can you tell me which part of my question was unclear so I can reiterate and improve it?

Comment: The problem is you are asking multiple questions in one. Your first question: Can I call the derived class constructor from the main class? By main, do you mean base? Your other question is about includes in main.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of misconceptions in the question:

1. You *never* "call a constructor". Syntax to do this does not exist. What you are trying to do is to declare, define, instantiate, create an object of type `Derived`.
2. You're attempt to do so from `main()`, not from the base class.
3. `main()` is a function, not a class.
4. No, you can't create a `Derived` without its definition. That its base is in scope is insufficient, and even if it weren't, the compiler has no way of knowing that a base is in scope, because it doesn't know what `Derived` is.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I call a derived class constructor from a base class?

If you mean *"Can I create derived class instances in a member function of a base class"*, then yes you can. An example:

```
struct Base {
    void foo();
};

struct Derived {
    Derived() {
        // a constructor
    }
};

void Base::foo() {
    Derived d; // "calling the constructor" of derived class
}
```

Exactly when would this be useful? Probably never.

---

> Can I call the Derived class constructor from the main class, if I only include Base class ?

No. You only create instances of classes (I assume that's what you mean by "call the constructor") that have been defined. If you don't include the definition, then you cannot create instances.

> Do I have to include "Derived.h" to call the constructor?

If that's where the class is defined, then yes. The class must be defined before it can be instantiated.

> What if I had 150 subclasses under one superclass? Do I have to include each one ?

If you're going to instantiate objects of 150 classes then yes, all 150 classes must be defined first. However, I suspect that's not something you need to do.

> To clarify what I mean. Can I do this?
>
> ```
> #include "Base.h"
>
> int main(){
>   Derived d;
> }
> ```

Depends on what `"Base.h"` contains. If it contains the definition of the `Derived` class (which would be unconventional), then yes. If it doesn't contain the definition of `Derived` (which would be conventional), then no.